# Web services testing using Webdriver(SE)

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver

Can we use selenium webdriver to test API. For example if we fill sign up form than can we check that API is called properly and the parameter we pass at sign up page are transfer at the web services?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Selenium webdriver is not supposed to test APIs. Yes but there are workaround you can do it in indirect way. But I'd suggest to use the tool which is meant to test APIs. There are few open source Java based DSL which you can use along with selenium.

One of them is [Rest Assured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/).

Personally I liked this tool and integrated it with my selenium project. I use selenium to perform all the front-end operations which are required to call APIs.